# Is it possible to config up and down buttons for input[type="number"] have different step than input validation?

Tags: html, html-input

I want a number input which:

- accept all integer values in range [0, 1000], (e.g. 42 is a valid value)
- reject all non-integer values, (e.g. 3.14 is an invalid value)
- when up / down button is pressed, the value increase / decrease by 10 (or increase to nearest *n* * 10)

It seems that `step` attribute config both input form validation and the behavior of up / down button. Is it possible for me that make a input have the described behavior?

Comment: please refer to [this article](https://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php).

Comment: @Umesh i'm asking input[type="number"], not range

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, a working example:

```html
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="1000" step="10">
```

You can specify the range by using the `min` and `max` attributes, and then for specifying how much to add or decrease on arrow click, you can set the `step` attribute.

Comment: But this violate the first requirement: values like `42` is not accepted by the input. the input will show a red outline on my browser, and it wont allow form submit if you put it in form.

Comment: @tsh in that case, you cannot achieve it only by HTML, you will need to use  javascript. Hope this helps!

Comment: @tsh, I think you need a custom input behavior here. What I understand that you need an input box which should accept values only in multiples of 10. In that case, as N. Ivanov mentioned, you need to use JS, possibly onChange/onBlur.

Comment: @Umesh I want "accept all integer values in range [0, 1000]" should I some how edit the question to make it more clearly?

Comment: @tsh to begin with add javascript/jquery tags, but I would advise you first to try and solve the problem by yourself using js. SO is not a free coding service. Thanks!

Comment: @N.Ivanov The question is about "how to use XYZ api to archive my request" not "how to code PQR myself". Not asking for code writing, Just asking if it is possible. I just cannot believe that there is no way to archive such a easy thing with the "powerful" html5. And i always prefer a solution without js, since you may not draw a input as same as the browser provided. (It vary from browser to browser, from os to os.) Adding another hidden input, copy the value oninput, and remove this input completely from the form would solve the question. But that is not what I want.